# how do you track the X and Y Coordinates of a Rectangle on a bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, opencv, bitmap

```
static readonly CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");

    void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        Image<Bgr, byte> grayImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
        Rectangle[] rectangles = cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.2, 1);
        foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangles)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5))
                {
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                }

            }
        }
        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
        webcamDetection.Image = bitmap;
    }
```

so this is the code i am using
my question how do i get the x and y values of the red rectangle so i can send those values to an arduino and set servos as such. I can provide more information, hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Di you put the rectangles there? if so, just keep track of them. If not you will have to scan each line

Comment: I think the coordinates of the rectangle were given by the face recognition, though I'm not sure, I am new to doing C#. If ever how can I scan each line? what I was thinking is comparing each pixel to the color of the pen but I don't know if that is possible to code.

Comment: I do not think the question is very clear. Does it concern how to detect a rectangle with a specified color in an image? or how to take a rectangle and send the coordinates to an arduino?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to get coordinates of the rectangle to send the arduino.

Comment: According to your description, you want to get the X, Y of the red rectangle. I suggest you could write a Picturebox_MouseClick event to get e.X, e.Y.

Comment: Does anyone know how to tag this question as answered? Because i found the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the rectangle you can check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=netcore-3.1) to see the available properties. You would typically use `rect.X`, `rect.Y`, `rect.Width`, and `rect.Height`.

Comment: Where can i find the documentation?

Comment: @alex456 Checked the link?

Comment: The link show how to create a rectangle using the values given, but I think the code I am using places the rectangle on the bitmap based on where it detects a face, I am trying to find a way to get the coordinates of that rectangle.

Comment: @alex456 if you check the properties section of the link you get exactly that.

Comment: @alex456 Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a code writing service. If you want to know how to write c# code, check a c# tutorial. If you want to know how to send values to an arduino you should post a new question asking that.